# How to add front-end(html/css) on my ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my .cshtml file that contain table of items. This table shows items that are for sale, and I want to add background image in this file. If it does not working please tell me how to attach background  for this.

I know cshtml is the file extension that refers to the razor view engine. In addition to straight html, these files also contain C# code that is compiled on the server prior to the pages being server up to the browser.

```html
@model IEnumerable<PakMall.Models.UserItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
  <p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "userItems", FormMethod.Get))
     {
    <p>
        Discription: @Html.DropDownList("discription", "All")
        Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
     }
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManufacturingDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Discription)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
           <!-- <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemImage)
            </th>-->
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ManufacturingDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact)
            </td>
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: are you trying to add a background image to the whole page?

Comment: yes I want add background in whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the `background-image` css class:

```
body {
    background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
  }
```

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) article is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

In _Layout.cshtml I added background image in like html format.
So _Layout.cshtml is file in .net web application where all pages layout can be designed.